# How to receive an output for a method from a closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, output, closures

How to receive an output of an array of [TweetSentimentClassifierInput] objects to send it further to my prediction model?

I have the array but inside a closure which turns it unavailable to return as a method output. If I initialize an empty array outside the closure then the output is always an empty array since fetch closure takes time to be completed.

Code

```
struct TweetFetcher {

   let tweetCount = 100
   let swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: key, consumerSecret: secret)

func fetchTweets(with searchText: String) -> [TweetSentimentClassifierInput] {
    
    swifter.searchTweet(using: searchText, lang: "en", count: tweetCount, tweetMode: .extended) {(results, searchMetadata) in
        var tweets = [TweetSentimentClassifierInput]()
        let data = results.description.data(using: .utf8)

        do {
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([TweetData].self, from: data!)
        } catch {
            print("Error with decoding, \(error)")
        }

        for tweet in decodedData {
            let tweetForClassification = TweetSentimentClassifierInput(text: tweet.full_text)
            tweets.append(tweetForClassification)
        }
    } failure: { (error) in
        print("Error with the Twitter API request, \(error)")
    }
}
}
```

How can I return a non-empty array from a closure as a method output?

Comment: convert this method in async, passing closure with [TweetSentimentClassifierInput] as closure argument

Comment: You can add your own closure/callback parameter to fetchTweets and pass it as an argument to that closure or add a property to your struct that you assign the array to in the closure

Comment: Unrelated but your code doesn't compile. The loop must be inside the `do` scope.

Comment: @vadian, thank you. Yes, you're wright. Just forgot to move it, it was a forced try for testing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `completionHandler` concept to achieve async operations like this:

```swift
struct TweetFetcher {
    let tweetCount = 100
    let swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: key, consumerSecret: secret)
    
    func fetchTweets(with searchText: String, completion: @escaping ([TweetSentimentClassifierInput]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        swifter.searchTweet(using: searchText, lang: "en", count: tweetCount, tweetMode: .extended) {(results, searchMetadata) in
            var tweets = [TweetSentimentClassifierInput]()
            let data = results.description.data(using: .utf8)
            
            do {
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([TweetData].self, from: data!)
            } catch {
                print("Error with decoding, \(error)")
                completion(nil, error)
            }
            
            for tweet in decodedData {
                let tweetForClassification = TweetSentimentClassifierInput(text: tweet.full_text)
                tweets.append(tweetForClassification)
            }
            completion(tweets, nil)
        } failure: { (error) in
            print("Error with the Twitter API request, \(error)")
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
let fetcher = TweetFetcher()
fetcher.fetchTweets(with: "Keyword...") { tweets, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        // Use tweets array content here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I successfully implemented your answer with some changes in my project. I have never used a completionHandler concept before (truth to be told I am just new to Swift). Can you suggest some articles for a deeper understanding of that concept?

Comment: You're welcome. Actually a completion handler is a form of the `closures` so I think you should know how the closures work to get better understanding of it. A good tutorial for completion handler can be found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-continuations-to-convert-completion-handlers-into-async-functions) and [here](https://www.codingem.com/swift-completion-handlers/)

Answer (score 0):

Convert this method in async, passing closure with `[TweetSentimentClassifierInput]` as closure argument, and an error as secondary closure argument,

```
func fetchTweets(with searchText: String, finished: ((_ sentiments: [TweetSentimentClassifierInput]?,_ error: Error?) -> Void)) {

    swifter.searchTweet(using: searchText, lang: "en", count: tweetCount, tweetMode: .extended) {(results, searchMetadata) in
        var tweets = [TweetSentimentClassifierInput]()
        let data = results.description.data(using: .utf8)

        do {
           let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([TweetData].self, from: data!)
           } catch {
           print("Error with decoding, \(error)")
        }

        for tweet in decodedData {
            let tweetForClassification = TweetSentimentClassifierInput(text: tweet.full_text)
            tweets.append(tweetForClassification)
        }
        finished(tweets, nil)
    } failure: { (error) in
        print("Error with the Twitter API request, \(error)")
        finished(nil, error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Reinier. But what if I need to to call the fetchTweets later in a ViewController? Then I should give the method a sentiment part which I don't have in that VC. Now I think maybe it's an easier just to combine my fetch and predict methods so I can pass the array just as where finished(tweets, nil)...